# Motorola MC9500 unable to connect to wireless network

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I'm trying to connect a unit to my home wireless network. I follow the setup as done at the client site but for some reason at my home network it writes an "Association timeout" error in "Wireless Status" -> "Wireless Log".

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I had to modify my 5 GHz wireless network settings. I changed the *Security mode* from *WPA2/WPA Mixed Personal* to *WPA2 Personal* (I use my 5 GHz network for mobile devices)

[image]

Other tips

1. When setting up the profile on the mobile device the ESSID is case SensItivE
2. The option to *Allow WPA2 Mixed Mode* on the mobile device wireless profile setup, I unchecked. Enabled resurfaces the issue above.
3. Soft restart the unit (some units you just hold the power button down for 5 seconds)